# Using Firefox for Play Framework integration tests

Tags: firefox, playframework

I've started a new Play application

`play new todolist`

I created project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "Your application"
  val appVersion      = "1.0"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
      "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-firefox-driver" % "2.40.0" % "test"
  )
}
```

I also modified test/IntegrationSpec.scala to use Firefox

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {

    "work from within a browser" in {
      running(TestServer(9000, application = FakeApplication()), FIREFOX) { browser =>

      browser.goTo("http://localhost:9000")

      browser.pageSource must contain("Your new application is ready.")
     }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `play test`, a Firefox browser starts, but it never goes to a url. The interesting parts from the exception are

`JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 648: aUrl is undefined`

and

`[error]     WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7057; process output follows:`

I've put a [gist here with the full stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/jdowns/0037b08de35d946be6cf).

What am I doing wrong? How do I get Firefox to work with Play Framework and actually run a test?

Comment: What version of firefox is it?

Comment: Are you under linux ?  Does firefox launch itself ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.  Firefox does launch when I run the test, it just doesn't go to a url and instead presents a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

If you still having the problem, I had a similar one and solved it updating the selenium dependency:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.43.0")
```

Hope it helps.